# `LAST_VALUE` Between two Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table

TableA

```
ASSIGNMENT_DT    START_DATE    END_DATE    CLT_ID  C_ID First_Service_Date FIRST_SERVICE_DATE2
    2/13/15       1/26/18         1/29/18     1      1                     1/30/18
    3/14/16       1/26/18         1/29/18     1      1                     1/30/18
    1/30/18       1/26/18         1/29/18     1      1                       NULL
```

Query:

```
,CASE WHEN FIRST_SERVICE_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN FIRST_SERVICE_DATE
  WHEN FIRST_SERVICE_DATE IS NULL AND ASSIGNMENT_DT > START_DATE THEN NULL
  WHEN FIRST_SERVICE_DATE IS NULL AND ASSIGNMENT_DT < START_DATE THEN LAST_VALUE(TRUNC(ASSIGNMENT_DT)) OVER (PARTITION BY CLT_ID
   ORDER BY CLIENTID ,ASSIGNMENT_DT RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)

ELSE TO_DATE('9999/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')

END FIRST_SERVICE_DATE2
```

What I need:
 The First_Service_Date2 column should have one Agg value per Clt_id. 
 So for the example, When End_Date is Not null take the previous assignment_dt that is less than the start date

When end_date is not null that the LEAD assignment date after the start_Date.

Should be

```
First_Service_Date
   3/14/16
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd split the query up and do a UNION.

```
select a.*,
  FIRST_SERVICE_DATE as FIRST_SERVICE_DATE2
from TableA a
where FIRST_SERVICE_DATE IS NOT NULL
    OR ASSIGNMENT_DT > START_DATE 
union all
select a.*,
  LAST_VALUE(TRUNC(ASSIGNMENT_DT)) OVER (PARTITION BY CLT_ID) as FIRST_SERVICE_DATE2
from TableA a
where FIRST_SERVICE_DATE IS NULL 
    AND ASSIGNMENT_DT < START_DATE
;
```

(I'm guessing here, since you didn't share your whole query, but I think this gets the idea across.)